# ReactJS dynamic component generation from JSON

Tags: reactjs

I've just started to learn ReactJS (with only basic knowledge of HTML/CSS/js) and I would like to build a site creates pictures dynamically from a JSON file which contains an image source, title, description, and href.

I am 100% sure that there are numerous and probably lacking all sorts of basic knowledge about how this works, so I apologize and appreciate your time and help.

Before trying to use react, I implemented it using only basic HTML/CSS/js, with a js function which looped through and insertAdjacentHtml'd it into a target div, [here](https://a12b4c3.github.io/p1-photoblog/) (warning, very slow and unoptimized - runs long scripts 170x). Now I'm trying to adapt it to react to get a sense of how it would work using components.

**my plan so far**
I made an app.js which I can npm start at which looks like the following. I created a container which I intend on using to hold all of the pictures. I believe I have 3 major problems (and knowledge gaps) at this moment.

**1)** I think one big problem for me here, is I have had a difficult time understanding how the components can get created and inserted into the app.js. In regular JS, it was easy to picture that the HTML was getting changed with every loop. Using react, I read tutorials which suggested using a map function to go through the JSON array, and at every loop create a component to be rendered. I'm sure that there's probably something wrong here already.

***app.js***

```
parseJson(){
    var data = require('./highlights.json');
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      var obj = data[i];
      console.log("source: " + obj.src);
      {
        return data.map((Highlight, key) =>
          <Highlight source={obj.src} link = {obj.href} title = {obj.title} desc = {obj.desc}/> // probably major problems with this.
          )
      }
    }
  }

render() {
return (
  <div className="App">
    <Menubar/>
    <div>
    <Profilepic onClick={this.toggleModal}/>
    </div>
    <div className = "HighlightsContainer"> // the container
    {this.parseJson()} // the function i intended on running to get the components made, problem 1.
    </div>
    <UploadButton/>
    <UploadWindow show={this.state.uploadWindowOpen}/>

    <Modal show={this.state.isOpen}
      onClose={this.toggleModal}>
      <Signup/>
    </Modal>
    <PhotoViewer show={this.state.photoViewerOn}/>
  </div>
);
}
```

I made the highlight component that is supposed to take the props and fill them in to create a component.

**2)** I'm not very familiar with props. The tutorials I have done show props being made with something like: `const componentName = (props) => { return <div>({props.aProp}</div>);};` but a tutorial I was looking at seemed to be able to use let statements to (get? make? save?) props. [tutorial here](http://react.tips/how-to-create-reactjs-components-dynamically/). It is almost certain that I simply do not understand how props can alternatively be passed along in a way similar to this.

***highlight.jsx***

```
import React from 'react';
let Highlight = function statelessFunctionComponentClass(props) {
let source = './images/' + props.source;
let link = props.link;
let title = props.title;
let desc = props.desc;

let style = {
    position: 'relative',
    width: '300px',
    height: '300px',
    background: 'blue',
    display: 'inline-block'
  };

  return (
    <div>
    <a href={link}>
    <img src={source} style={style}/>
    </a>
    <div id="highlight1-title">{title}</div>
    <div id="highlight1-desc">{desc}</div>
    </div>
    );
};

export default Highlight;
```

Finally, here is the JSON file.

***highlights.json***

```
[
    {
        "src": "1.jpg",
        "title": "Day 1: Short Title",
        "desc": "some description",
        "href": "#"
    },
    {
        "src": "2.jpg",
        "title": "Day 4: Medium title Words",
        "desc": "some description 2",
        "href": "#"
    }
]
```

**longer term concerns**

**3)** Eventually, I would like to implement [the aforementioned version](https://a12b4c3.github.io/p1-photoblog/) of the site using react, some kind of SQL server for some permanence in the site and to somehow (don't know yet) stop the site from needing to rerun the script every single time the page loads. More importantly, the previous implementation is shown above relied heavily on creating 7 unique styles for each component so that each picture has unique background colors, onhover effects - resulting in a bloated style sheet. *What is the best way to approach styling of dynamically generated components that each need to have their own onhover and unique background colors and will behave well for 5 or 300 components?*

Thank you for your time and patience!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `parseJson` should be like this

```
parseJson(){
   var data = require('./highlights.json');
   return data.map((obj, key) =>
       <Highlight source={obj.src} link={obj.href} title={obj.title} desc={obj.desc}/> 
   )
}
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for the comment. You're right and I have fixed the map function. It seems to be generating the correct number of elements form JSON as well as filling it out with the correct alt and href information now. Suggesting that my prop variables seem to be correctly implemented (comments always welcome). I will mark this as the answer, given that I think the scope of my question is probably too big to receive replies - I will cut down the scope in future inquiries. Thank you!